# full calendar event drop is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar

I am making the reservation website by using full calendar. I want to change the date that user booked by dragging the event to other place. However, the drag is worked, but drop is not working. When I drop the event, then the event just disappear, and when I reload the page, then it appear where it used to be.

Here is code for javascript

```
    $(function() { // document ready

    var originalDate;

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        eventDragStart: function(event) {
            originalDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm");  // Make a copy of the event date
        },

        eventDrop:function(event)
        {
         var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm");
         //get new Date

         var id = event.id; //get userID who booked this event 




             $.ajax({
              url:"http://show981111.cafe24.com/login-system/update.php",
              type:"POST",
              data:{newlyBookedDate: start, userID: id, oldDate: originalDate}, // send data 


              success:function()
              {
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                    alert("Date has changed.");
                    location.reload();
              }                    
             });



        },
```

Here is code for update.php.
What I am trying to do here is get the changed Date, and update the newly booked Date,which had the old Date, to newly booked Date, which is changed Date when I get from eventDrop.

```
<?php



$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=show981111', 'show981111', 'pass');

if(isset($_POST["newlyBookedDate"]))
{
 $query = "UPDATE DAYSCHEDULE SET newlyBookedDate = :newlyBookedDate WHERE userID = :userID AND newlyBookedDate = :oldDate ";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute(
  array(

    ':newlyBookedDate' => $_POST['newlyBookedDate'],
    ':userID' => $_POST['userID'],
    ':oldDate' => $_POST['oldDate']


 ));
}
```

?>

I checked console, and have this error:

```
fullcalendar.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined
at function.e.constructor.buildNewDateProfile (fullcalendar.min.js:10)
at function.e.constructor.mutateSingle (fullcalendar.min.js:10)
at function.e.constructor.R.internalApiVersion.f.mutateSingle (scheduler.min.js:6)
at fullcalendar.min.js:10
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at constructor.mutateEventsWithId (fullcalendar.min.js:10)
at reportEventDrop (fullcalendar.min.js:9)
at fullcalendar.min.js:7
at i (fullcalendar.min.js:7)
at constructor.stop (fullcalendar.min.js:7)
```

Comment: Side note: `$.fullCalendar.formatDate` is deprecated and may not work correctly. Since fullCalendar 2.0 you should be using momentJS to format dates. Because `event.start` is already a moment object, you can just do `event.start.format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm");` instead

Comment: Anyway, since you dragged your event, it should move on the calendar automatically. There should be no need to call refetchEvents, nor should there be any need to reload the page - reloading the page destroys the effect of both the dragging and the refetch anyway, it makes all the prior code pointless. There should in theory be no reason why the dragging wouldn't work - unless you have some error in your console which is making it crash...did you check for that?

Comment: Also your UPDATE statement is a bit odd....why do you match on the oldDate? There could easily be multiple events on the same date/time...are you sure it's updating the correct event (if it manages to update anything at all?). Don't you have a unique event ID you can use? I notice you used the event ID in fullCalendar to hold the user ID...you could use a custom field for that instead if needed, but if you have a unique event ID you probably wouldn't require it anyway.

Comment: I didn't use any unique event ID, but user only can book for one Date, so I use userID and oldDate in the WHERE condition. Now, I find a weird situation that when I drag the event and drop it, it disappear. However, when I drag other event, then the event that disappeared appear and when I drop it, it worked properly, even if the success function in ajax is not working.

Comment: Hmm, I can't reproduce that behaviour from a quick test. Can you make a demo using JSFiddle or CodePen which shows the problem in action (you can mock the AJAX request if you're saying that doesn't seem to make any difference)?

Comment: @ADyson I checked console and got Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined, I uploaded all of Error on my question.

Comment: Again I'm afraid I don't get that error when working with eventDrop. As a guess, perhaps there is a problem with your event data somewhere. Anyway, if you need more help you'll have to create a runnable demo which reproduces the issue. You can use JSFiddle, CodePen or even a StackSnippet here. In fact, here's a JSFiddle to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/7e6rob2c/ Modify that until it reproduces your error. If you need a pretend AJAX endpoint to simulate the AJAX request, make use of http://myjson.com/